# How to populate second drop down by using the selection of first drop down in django?

Tags: django

I have tree dropdowns ! Lets say Drop1, Drop2, Drop3. Now each populates data's from database. Now my problem is as below.

I need to somehome populate the Drop2 data based on Drop1 and Drop3 data based on Drop2. Lets say if user selects

```
Drop1 - Option A //selected

By using this Option A i need to filter and fetch data for Drop2

Drop2 - Option A2 // fetched based on Drop1 Selection

And same applies to Drop3
```

How to handle this ? I have populated the data for Drop1, but confused on how to select for Drop2 based on Drop1. Please guide

Thank you. I dont know what code to share, so please let me know if you guys need anything

Comment: The `django-autocomplete-light` package has support for this functionality https://django-autocomplete-light.readthedocs.io/en/master/tutorial.html#filtering-results-based-on-the-value-of-other-fields-in-the-form

Comment: How to do that without a plugin @IainShelvington

Comment: use Ajax to , check this link https://simpleisbetterthancomplex.com/tutorial/2018/01/29/how-to-implement-dependent-or-chained-dropdown-list-with-django.html